# Change engine of a table having foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, alter-table

I'm trying to write a script that change engine of certain table to MEMORY.
The script look like:

```
Echo SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; > %TmpFile%
Echo ALTER TABLE `%Database%`.`compare_review` ENGINE = MEMORY; >> %TmpFile%
Echo SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; >> %TmpFile%

mysql -h %host% -u %User% -p%Pwd% < %TmpFile%
```

When I run this script, I got the error: **Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails**

I wonder what causes this error because the sql file contains command: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`

I'm sure FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 because I try to put a command `Select @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` to check, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the engine for the table to one which doesn't support foreign keys without removing the foreign key constraints.

[Documentation for the MEMORY engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html)

If the new engine doesn't support them, they simply can't exist, so you need to remove them before making the appropriate changes.